# Testing Google Compute API within a sandbox

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there any way to test Google Compute Engine API calls within a sandboxed environment for development/testing purposes? For example, to invoke an API call to create instances without having to create (and then pay for) actual instances.

Thanks

Comment: What's your use case? What are you trying to achieve?